# How to "access only" an link, using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an `arduino webserver` server and an `normal webserver`
Comunication betwen this servers is using link sistem like:

Normal Webserver to Arduiono Server:

- ArduinoServer/light1=on - Light is on
- ArduinoServer/light1=off - Light is off

Arduino Webserver to Normal Webserver:

- NormalWebserver/temperature=22&humidity=56&light1=on
- NormalWebserver/temperature=22&humidity=56&light1=off

The comunicaton is working well but the problem is with the action buttons, when I am switching the light, i need `just to access` the eternal `arduino websever link` and I am also using the `ajax` to check the light statement.

If the light statement is changed, my div.id="light1" takes new javascript content and my old code to prevent the redirect to `arduino webserver` is not working anymore.

The old code to `'acces only'` the link in the button:

```
// Attach click handler to all 'access-only' links.
$('a.access-only').click(function() {
    // Once the link is clicked, access its URL with a GET request.
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
        // Do nothing here, the URL has been accessed.
    });

    // Return false to prevent the browser's default click action.
    return false;
});
```

But I need a code to do this even with the new content from the `ajax`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a *event delegation* istead of a *event handler*, because you have dynamically generated contents. On your `$.get` you can remove the callback. It's not needed, if you don't want to do any further things. And you should use `preventDefault` to breaking the `click` execution on the `a` tag.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.access-only', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```